# Perl SOAP::LITE service generated stub method within method

Tags: perl, web-services, wsdl, soaplite

I have a SOAP::Lite client using the service method to grab a wsdl.  This needs to call a webservice with a single operation and method with no parameters.  It's resulting in a nested method call that the provider tells me is wrong.  And I'm not very knowledgeable about SOAP::Lite or webservices.  Advice appreciated!

```
my $lookup = SOAP::Lite->service('http://hostname.com/path/SpringVerifierWebServicePort?wsdl')
    -> proxy("$theURL") ;
$response = $lookup->verifySpring('');
```

And that is generating this stub on the call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.springverifier.toolslang.fedins.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    <soap:Body>
      <tns:verifySpring>
         <verifySpring xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="tns:verifySpring" />
      </tns:verifySpring>    </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP::Response=HASH(0x167bee8)
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

The provider of that webservice tells me the 500 error is due to the nested verifySpring on the call. Do I need to call this differently than I am, or is the WSDL invalid and screwing up SOAP::Lite?   I don't know enough about SOAP and webservices to say if the problem is the WSDL, or if I need to call this differently in SOAP::LITE.  Could anyone give me some direction please?

The provider WSDL is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.springverifier.toolslang.fedins.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="SpringVerifierWebServiceService" targetNamespace="http://webservice.springverifier.toolslang.fedins.com">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.springverifier.toolslang.fedins.com" targetNamespace="http://webservice.springverifier.toolslang.fedins.com" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="verifySpring" type="tns:verifySpring" /> 
      <xs:element name="verifySpringResponse" type="tns:verifySpringResponse" /> 
      <xs:complexType name="verifySpring">
        <xs:sequence /> 
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="verifySpringResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:environmentInfo" /> 
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="environmentInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dbRegion" type="xs:string" /> 
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="jndi" type="xs:string" /> 
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="springProfile" type="xs:string" /> 
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="systemDate" type="xs:string" /> 
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="verifySpringResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:verifySpringResponse" name="parameters" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="verifySpring">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:verifySpring" name="parameters" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SpringVerifierWebService">
    <wsdl:operation name="verifySpring">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:verifySpring" name="verifySpring" /> 
      <wsdl:output message="tns:verifySpringResponse" name="verifySpringResponse" /> 
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="SpringVerifierWebServiceServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:SpringVerifierWebService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
    <wsdl:operation name="verifySpring">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" /> 
      <wsdl:input name="verifySpring">
        <soap:body use="literal" /> 
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="verifySpringResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal" /> 
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SpringVerifierWebServiceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:SpringVerifierWebServiceServiceSoapBinding" name="SpringVerifierWebServicePort">
      <soap:address location="http://dev1.spring.service.fedins.com/fedservice/toolslang/springverifier/webservice/services/SpringVerifierWebServicePort" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

'' is an actual value (empty string), use `verifySpring();` and not `verifySpring('');`
Example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;
use SOAP::Lite;
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> uri('http://127.0.0.1/MyModule')
    -> proxy('http://127.0.0.1:1203')
;;;;;;;;;
$soap->readable(1);
$soap->transport->add_handler("request_send",  sub { print $_[0]->as_string,"\n"; return } );
eval { $soap->verifySpring(''); 1 } or print "$@\n";
eval { $soap->verifySpring();   1 } or print "$@\n";
__END__
POST http://127.0.0.1:1203 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml
Accept: multipart/*
Accept: application/soap
User-Agent: SOAP::Lite/Perl/1.11
Content-Length: 522
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://127.0.0.1/MyModule#verifySpring"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <verifySpring xmlns="http://127.0.0.1/MyModule">
      <c-gensym3 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
          </verifySpring>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

500 Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:1203 at - line 11.

POST http://127.0.0.1:1203 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml
Accept: multipart/*
Accept: application/soap
User-Agent: SOAP::Lite/Perl/1.11
Content-Length: 475
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://127.0.0.1/MyModule#verifySpring"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <verifySpring xmlns="http://127.0.0.1/MyModule" xsi:nil="true" />
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

500 Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:1203 at - line 12.
```